# Populate from dropdown list using Vlookup

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Im an excel Noob. So any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have created a table in excel with the several different bits of data.

i have 3 Sheets; 
Sheet1 is for data input it contains 3 Columns:

Sheet 2 contains a table with data.
It is structured like this;
[My Table Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3pqL.png)

Sheet3 Is the output sheet its combine the columns from sheet 1 and the attributes in sheet 3,
[Output Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uiKK.png)

Scenario:

So what ever options was picked in the dropdown list it would get those attributes(from Sheet2) and display in the correct columns( in Sheet 3)

ive tried to do this using Vlookup formula;

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(tbl_items[[#Headers],[Attribute]],tbl_items,4,0),"")
```

but when i click an item from the dropdown list no data is pulled from the table and populated in `Sheet3`

Thanks

UPDATE 1:
I can get it to work for one Column using this formula;

```
=VLOOKUP(A52,tbl_items,5,FALSE)
```

This pulls the data from `Column 5`, how can i get it to pull from more then one column now?

Comment: It sounds like you might benefit from some Vlookup tutorials, [like this one](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Vlookup-Tutorial.html). Vlookup will only ever get results from a single column. Am I to understand you want results from several columns? The best thing to do would be to concatenate two separate vlookups together in that case.

Comment: @neophlegm, thank you for your help , yes that is correct i would want results from several coulmns